# Hide view and re position other views accordingly

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I have some action buttons bellow my table view items. There are 7 items. However, some times, some action buttons will be hidden. However, when I hide an item, the positions stay same as you can see in the image:

[image: My items]
[image: My items after hide]

[image: My constraints are looking like this]

How can I make sure other items fill out its position?

Comment: if you don't need to support iOS 8, use `UIStackView`.

Comment: What do you mean by a parent view of action buttons?

Comment: But when I make the parent view hidden, will the other views adjust their positions automatically?

Comment: I think I got your question wrong . You want  that space gone with the button hide ?

Comment: I want the space gone, I can already make the button gone with button.hidden = true

Answer (score 0):

take `outlets` of `constraints` and change `constant` of constraints as per requirement.

according to your example take outlet of `attach button's leading constraint`(left constraint) and reduce it's constant with hidden button's width (forward button's width in your case) + reduce space between buttons.

you can connect outlet from just ctrl+drag from respective constraint to class with assistant editor open.

example;

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttonLeadingConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint?
```

then change

```
self.buttonLeadingConstraint.constant = self.buttonLeadingConstraint.constant - 50;

 // here 50 is space between button + button width
```

hope this will help :)

Comment: In additional [self.view layoutIfNeeded]

Comment: I wanted to avoid dealing with constraints but I guess its the only way. Thanks!

Comment: it is best way i think because your all elements will manage by just changing one constraints's constant.